# Pytorch - round tensor values to nearest value in a list

Tags: pytorch

Given a tensor of values is there an efficient way to round every value in the tensor to the closest value in a list? So let's say I have tensor [[.5, .25],[1.2,2]] and list of values [0, 1, 2] then it should round the example tensor values to [[1, 0],[1,2]] (ties are broke arbitrarily)

Comment: How about using `torch.round`?

Comment: that only rounds to the nearest decimal place that would work for the above example but not if the list of values is [0.333, 0.666, 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this for each value in the tensor, although you need to convert the list to a tensor first:

```
val = torch.tensor([0.33])

vals = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.5, 0.7])

def discretize(contValue: torch.tensor, discValues: torch.tensor) -> torch.tensor:

    diff    = discValues - contValue

    absDiff = torch.abs(diff)

    minIdx  = torch.argmin(absDiff)

    dt      = contValue + diff[minIdx]

    return dt

discretize(val, vals)
```

This yields 0.5 for the given input.